# centos 7 firewall-cmd --panic-on idle

Tags: centos7, panic, firewalld

Here I am exploring the security features, and when I enter "firewall-cmd --panic-on" to the CLI, the system just hangs idle.

Centos 7
Kernel 3.10

I think this is not supposed to happen, b/c as I read the documentation, I see I should be able to firewall-cmd --panic-off, but I cannot even ssh through another terminal unless I restart the server.

Is the system corrupt?

Is there a bug with "firewall-cmd --panic-on"?

How can I figure out the source of the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
>    --panic-on
>        Enable panic mode. All incoming and outgoing packets are dropped, active connections will expire. Enable this only if there are
> ```
>
> serious problems with your network environment. For example if the
> machine is getting hacked in.
> As this switch drops all incoming connections and kills established active connections, so you can not issue **--panic-off** using ssh. You have to run **firewall-cmd --panic-off** using console access. running `firewall-cmd --panic-on` will apply configuration in runtime level so by simply restarting the server you can access ssh session. never run `firewall-cmd --panic-on --permanent` you can verify panic status by running `firewall-cmd --query-panic`

Comment: Yes Ali, setting the panic mode from the console worked. Thank you